# Send SMS twilio by postman through wso2

Tags: wso2, twilio, postman, sms, esb

I want to Send SMS twilio  by postman through Wso2 ESB , the body , to and from parameters submitted through postman to wso2 sequence , I'm trying to do it by payloadFactory but it does not work , it said :

```
<TwilioResponse>
<RestException>
    <Code>21602</Code>
    <Message>Message body is required.</Message>
    <MoreInfo>https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21602</MoreInfo>
    <Status>400</Status>
</RestException>
```

I'm using   https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC*****************/Messages
as endpoint to send it to Twilio
**my sequence :**

```
 <property expression="json-eval($.Body)" name="Body" scope="default"
        type="STRING" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    <property expression="json-eval($.To)" name="To" scope="default"
        type="STRING" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    <property expression="json-eval($.From)" name="From" scope="default"
        type="STRING" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    <payloadFactory media-type="json">
        <format>       {    "Body": $1,    "From": $2  ,"To": $3   }                         </format>
        <args>
            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('Body')"
                literal="false" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('From')"
                literal="false" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('To')"
                literal="false" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
        </args>
    </payloadFactory>
    <call>
        <endpoint key="twill2"/>
    </call>
    <send/>
```

**and my postman request :**

```
{
"Body":"hi dear",
"To":"+(***) *******",
"From":"+1 *******"
}
```

Comment: As per the error response, it seems that you are not sending the message body with the request. Can you invoke this endpoint directly with the postman. If so, please attach the request header and the body required for the request.

Comment: I post it in postman directly , it's work , the body is (From ,To , Body ), but as endpoint it is can not access the content for that it asked for body

Comment: If possible can you attach a screenshot of the postman request and also please attach the synapse configuration used to invoke the endpoint from EI

Comment: please check my question , I edit it with the the code of sequence and postman request ,as comment restrict on numbers of letters

Answer (score 0):

We have observed that in some cases even though the body is present in the request endpoints returning this error. This is due to the additional headers present or absence of some headers. Can you please try adding the following properties prior to the endpoint call

```
<property action="remove" name="TRANSPORT_HEADERS" scope="axis2"/>
<property name="setCharacterEncoding" scope="axis2" value="false"/>
<property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" scope="axis2" value="true"/>
<property name="ContentType" scope="axis2" value="application/json"/>
```

You can refer to the documentation [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKQEy.png), [2], [3], [4] for additional details on the above properties.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKQEy.png)-https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Generic+Properties#GenericProperties-TRANSPORT_HEADERS

[2]-https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI6xx/Axis2+Properties#Axis2Properties-setCharacterEncoding

[3]-https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/HTTP+Transport+Properties#HTTPTransportProperties-DISABLE_CHUNKINGDISABLE_CHUNKING

[4]-https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Generic+Properties#GenericProperties-ContentType

Updated

Can you enable wire in ESB server and attach logs when you invoke the endpoint directly. Refer to the blog [5] on enabling wire logs. Also please attach the curl command of the postman request. You can obtain this by selecting the code button in postman and selecting curl.

[image]

[5]-http://lakshanigamage.blogspot.com/2015/03/how-to-enable-wire-logs-in-wso2-esbapim.html

Comment: Thank you Shanaka , I added the properties but it returns this error : Your AccountSid or AuthToken was incorrect. even I specify AccountSid and AuthToken as password and username as basicAuth in postman

Comment: what are the headers that need to be passed to the endpoint? Can you please attach a screenshot or the curl command that is generated from the postman. Also, can you try to remove the TRANSPORT_HEADERS property and try with the other 3 properties?

Comment: the header is Authorization and I  I specify AccountSid and AuthToken as password and username in basic Auth , I removed TRANSPORT_HEADERS , same error, I do not know how share screenshot

Comment: the error as first time , body required, the postman curl is : curl --location --request POST 'http://0.0.0.0:0000/a/twill' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic ***********MGE4OTNlYg==' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
"Body":"hi dear",
"To":"+*********",
"From":"+1 *******"
}'

Comment: As requested try to attach the wire logs as well, meanwhile can you please attach the twill2 endpoint configuration as well.

Comment: <TwilioResponse><RestException><Code>21602</Code><Message>Message body is required.</Message><MoreInfo>https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21602</MoreInfo><Status>400</Status></RestException></TwilioResponse>[\r][\n]                                                    the endpoint : https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC*****************/Messages

Comment: I add attachment please check it

Comment: the attached screenshot contain only the response. Can you attach the request as well

Comment: attached , you can check it

Comment: can you check again? It does not seem to have the required attachment